# Drill Through Issue in Cognos using SAP BW Data Source

Tags: cognos, sap-bw

We created 2 reports,

Parent and Child, using a package created out of `BEX` query of `SAP BW`.

This `BEX` query consist of mandatory variables and these are prompted in the reports.

Problem what we are facing is, *when we drill through from parent report to child report the mandatory variable are re-prompted in the child rather than selecting he one we already chosen for parent report*.

In the drill through definition we did add these variables to pass the value but still it is prompted in the child report.

What is the workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'Drill Through Definitions' Dialog -> Target Report Tab

There is a dropdown at the bottom called 'Display Prompt Pages'.  In this drop down select **'Only when required parameter values are missing'**.

Your target report's 'Required' parameters should all be parameters being fed in from the Source report you are drilling through.  Any parameters in the target report that are not being fed in from the drill through report need to be set as Optional.

If the prompt page is still appearing, you have one of your variables not being passed between drill through to target, or you have an extra required parameter in the target report that needs to be set to optional.

One way to diagnose this is to Hard Code all of the parameters in the target report except for one.  Setup drill through for that one value and make sure it works without a prompt page when drilling.  Once you have that one variable working, add in remaining varaibles from the source.  If you are still having problems, you may need to add the variables in one at a time until you determine what is causing the problem.

Often just recreating the drill through you will notice a parameter you missed and catch it the second time.

[IBM Guide: Create a drill-through definition](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cx/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.0.doc/t_id_cr_rptstd_modrep_drill_through_access_110createadrill-throughdefinition.html)